# Cannot discover device on network

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall

I cannot see my Android Pie device on my local network (WiFi). The firewall (NetGuard) is down. No other firewall is installed as far as I know. I am trying to see it from my computer, (running Manjaro Linux).

The IP is 192.168.1.3

`nmap` doesn't find it on 192.168.1.*

`ping 192.168.1.3` gives:

```
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

`arping -D -c 3 -I enp3s0f1 192.168.1.3` receives 0 responses.

I need to make the phone discoverable in order to integrate it with the laptop. What is going on?

Comment: *"From **192.168.1.6** icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable"* indicates that your PC is unable to resolve `192.168.1.3` to a MAC address i.e. ARP resolution fails as you have explicitly tested. This problem is more about networking than Android. A very common reason for ARP resolution failure is WiFi **Access Point Isolation**. Check your WiFi router settings. Using `tcpdump` (or similar) listen for ARP broadcasts on Android device to make sure it receives ARP request messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSID isolation was enabled on the router. This has nothing to do with the clients. SSID isolation had to be disabled on the router and the machines discovered each other.

Thanks to @Irfan Latiff